# Block matrices without lines

Tags: matrices, arrays

I want to latex the following matrix

[image]

is there a solution without using arrays? Also, what will be the most efficient way to write this? 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate a little bit? I don't see how to solve my problem with the given suggestion.

Comment: No thanks, got it. I have the matrix I wanted with the dotted lines. Can i modify this code given in the other anser to get rid of the lines?

Comment: In the other answer there is something like `\begin{BMAT}(rc){c:c}{c:c}`.  The `:` denote the dotted lines, i.e. to get the example without any lines use `\begin{BMAT}(rc){cc}{cc}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pmatrix` and `matrix`s from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
A                                 & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} x & y \end{matrix} & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]